# HttpHandler not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mapping, httphandler

I am trying to integrate the FileUpload project from vid.ly to my web application which is in MVC ASP .NET 4 framework using Razor engine.

I have an HttpHandler under App_Code.
Progress.cs

```
public class Progress : IHttpHandler
{
 ...
}
```

I added this in RegisterRoutes() called from Globals.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Progress.progress");
```

And added these lines in system.web section in web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.progress" type="MyNamespace.Progress"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

When I try to open `http://localhost:39234/Progress.progress`, I get a `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` error with below detailed information:

```
Requested URL      http://localhost:39234/Progress.progress
Physical Path      c:\users\xxxxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SolutionName\ProjectName\Progress.progress
```

Seems like something is wrong with the mapping. Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. I had to put the mappings in `system.webServer` section in this format:

```
<add name="Progress" verb="*" path="*.progress" type="MyNamespace.Progress,MyNamespace"/>
```

Or, set the Action Build Path to "Content" for the Progress.cs files so that it doesn't get compiled in the MyNamespace.dll